# Rank SQL with multiple tables and filters

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using PHP to pull data from specific locations and trying to setup the SQL inquiry to look at a specific location by the rank. The inquiry needs to have two tables joined to be able to filter the results. The first table has column that I want the ranking to be based on where the second table has the filter. The tables I have are similar to

```
table1
itemA* | itemB | itemC | itemD | itemE | itemRank


table2
itemA* | itemB | itemC | itemD

* primary key
```

My ultimate goal is to get the row number/rank of an item in itemA (primary key) column.
This is my current code.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY table1.itemC DESC) AS table1.itemRank 
FROM table1 JOIN table2 WHERE table1.itemA = table2.itemA AND table2.itemD = "Y";
```

The column table1.itemRank doesn't have any data in it and want it to be able to change depending on the column I would like to rank by - itemB, itemC, itemD and itemE are all different types of data values of each of the primary keys/itemA.

This is the error that pops up:

```
1. An alias was previously found. (near "`itemRank`" at position 55)
2. An alias was expected. (near " " at position 54)
3. Unexpected token. (near "`itemRank`" at position 55)
```

Comment: you are right...i adjusted it to add mysql and remove php. Thanks!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use table1. as an alias. table1 already refers to table1. This query will return itemA from table1 with the rank, which is what I understand you are trying to do.

```
SELECT table1.itemA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY table1.itemC DESC) AS itmerank
FROM table1 JOIN table2 WHERE table1.itemA = table2.itemA AND table2.itemD = "Y";
```